# Vertically align text bottom - absolute position, without knowing width

Tags: css

I'm getting stumped here...
I'm trying to vertically align text in a top nav that has two different lines on each li.
Normally, I would take the position:relative + position:absolute route, however, that only works if you set the width of the element.

In my navigation, we don't have a standard width, but need all items aligned by the bottom text.

Here's my code

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">first line</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second<br />Line</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">third Line</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#menu {
    margin: 40px auto 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #666666;
    float: right;
    width:600px;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
}

#menu ul li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 11px;
    padding:5px 0;

}

#menu ul li a {
    color:#666666;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    display:block;
    line-height:1em;
    height:30px;

}
```

As you can see in the second li, there is a linebreak.
What I need is all the items to line up on the bottom, however, I can't use the width element.

Any help would be appreciated... javascript, jquery, are acceptable alternatives as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you appear to know the height (or optimal height) you could use the length value of `vertical-align` from [vertical-align specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align):

> **`<length>`**
>
> Raise (positive value) or lower
>   (negative value) the box by this
>   distance. The value '0cm' means the
>   same as 'baseline'

and if you make your `<a>` elements into inline blocks you then lower them by half the height, e.g. as below I took your height value of 30px, and made the links have a line height of 15px for each line then lowered it by 15px, which is 15px from the default middle point.

```
#menu {
    margin: 40px auto 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #666666;
    float: right;
    width:600px;
    background: #eee;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 11px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #dad;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color:#666666;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -15px;  
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

#### Working Example : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/QZdFC/)

downside is that I don't think you can get the whole 30px height hoverable, ike if the link was `display:block`, but maybe someone can expand on this if that's required, maybe it could be achieved by adding a `span` into the mix?

Answer (score 4):

See http://jsfiddle.net/HKAn2/1/ for the updated CSS and sample.

Updated fiddle sample with proper IE7 support: http://jsfiddle.net/HKAn2/3/.

I do not recommend using the CSS hacks in this fiddle example. Instead use an IE7 specific stylesheet to add the asterisked properties. This is just a sample.

Note the changes to

```
#menu ul li {
    display:inline-block; /* this */
    margin:0 11px;
    padding:5px 0;
    *display:inline; /* this  - IE7 */
    *zoom:1; /* this - IE7 */
}
```

and

```
#menu ul li a {
    color:#666666;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:1em;
    vertical-align:bottom; /* this */
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

I should further explain that the height property on your `a` element is no longer a requirement. The `a` will align to the bottom of the `li` element based on the `li` with the largest height.

Comment: this doesn't quite work in IE7, there's an errant `display:block` still on the `a` and the `inline-block` hack on the `li` is not quite right but it can be sorted, [**refiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/HKAn2/2/).. hth

Comment: @claire You are absolutely correct. I'll update the post with your corrections.